# Merging music and video file in flutter

Tags: flutter

I intend to provide a music file as a background music while recording a video. I want to have the music to start only when the video starts recording. I am an undergraduate student currently trying out flutter for a passion project, my professors has been no more useful than a phone in a plane.

I am unsure where to begin as this is my first time working on flutter. But I have looked through pub.dev and other repository.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to check out a package that wraps ffmpeg. The most promising one looks to be [ffmpeg_kit_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter). From there, use the package to extract the audio from the video, merge it with the audio from the music file, then replace the audio for the video.